# Group membership claims not included in id_token from Azure

Tags: azure, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have added the option to log in to my (multi-tenant) web application using Azure OAuth2:

When a user logs in, the application gets an authorization code from Microsoft.
The application then uses the authorization code to request an access token.
An "id_token" with additional information is send together with the access token.
This information includes the user's security group's ObjectIDs.
(*In the Azure portal in my application's manifest, I changed the "groupMembershipClaims" setting to "SecurityGroup".*)

This has been working properly for two and a half years, but since last week the group's ObjectID's are not included in the id_token anymore.
(*I haven't seen any recent changes related to this in Microsoft's documentation and I haven't found anything via Google.*)

- I tried changing the value of the "groupMembershipClaims" setting to "All", but this did not solve the problem.
- Recently we have integrated Skype for Business Online (*into the same web application*) using Azure OAuth's Implicit Flow, so I tried disabling the Implicit Flow ("oauth2AllowImplicitFlow" setting in the application's manifest in Azure): this did not solve the problem either.
  (*This should not make a difference from what I see, since the application still uses OAuth's authorization flow when users log in. The implicit flow is only used for the Skype part.*)

Comment: There's a limit on how many groups are included in the token (I think it's 20), at which point they'll no longer be included and you need to query the Graph... is that maybe what happened in your case? See https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2014/12/18/azure-active-directory-now-with-group-claims-and-application-roles/

Comment: In my situation there is no "groups" claim in the id_token.  Btw, the user I'm currently using to test this issue only has 2 groups (1 security group, 1 office group), so a limit should not be the issue in this case.